# Delegation in iOS without a protocol?

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, design-patterns, delegates

The Apple docs for Delegation state:

> In both Swift and Objective-C delegation ***is often expressed*** with
>   a protocol that defines the interaction and a conforming delegate
>   property

I'm not sure of any other way to create delegates that don't **"have to"** involve a protocol. Is there another way of expressing delegation in Swift or Objective-C that doesn't involve a protocol?

Comment: Nothing at all is wrong with protocols. Just thought it might be an opportunity to learn something about delegates design pattern that I wasn't aware of. I found the wording used in the docs to mean there are other ways to create a delegate not involving a protocol. Should I delete this question you think?

Comment: Protocols are the best way for delegates. It is a well tested design pattern that let two objects that don't know each other to comniucate between them. (Sorry for my spelling errores).

Comment: @Dasem yeah I get that. I'm not having a problem with delegates so maybe I should delete this question it was more of a "if protocols" are just 1 way of doing delegation what would be the other ways?

Comment: I think you can use closures or notifications, for comiunications but, i think protocols are the best way for the task. You don't to delete the question be cause someone more experince then me may  give you a better answer :-)

Comment: I agree with you and matt_roo about using the protocol to enforce the contract. Perhaps I shouldn't cling onto the wording so much with the Apple docs. It just really got me curious because I can't see a good solution for delegation without protocols so thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A delegate doesn't have to conform to a protocol. You can code to an implementation, but that is bad practice.

I think apple are saying that this is the way things are normally done. You don't have to use protocols...but you should if you want to keep things flexible.

Delegation is in essence asking someone else to do something for you. If you enforce a contract, then its more likely they will do it for you.

Comment: I agree 100% thanks for the second opinion with the choice of wording in the Apple docs. I would think Apple would say that "Excluding the protocol/s is a bad practice" but I guess I'm being over analytical about the sentence.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I Completely agree with the above answer, protocols guarantee the contract between the two objects. If there was no protocol, you cannot make sure that delegate methods are implemented in a way you require them to be.

Even if you use a class instead of a protocol, there can be problems regarding multiple inheritance and the implementation becomes difficult. This also leads to tight coupling between the objects and memory management becomes difficult.

However, in my point of view you can implement delegation without a protocol this way :

1. Forget the protocol, one delegate and one delegating object.
2. Its is developer's responsibility to implement all the required methods in the delegate object.
3. The variable 'delegate' will be of type class instead of protocol.
4. Call the appropriate methods directly whenever required.